Airbyte CDC replication from Postgres of geometry fields
I have an issue with replication done by Airbyte from PG table with geometry type field.
On most records I receive the value as json with the following structure:
{"wkb":"AQEAACDmEAAAKII4DyeNVMDmkNRCyZg8QA==","srid":"4326"}

But on some records from the same table, I receive it in the following format:
0101000020E6100000F1D8CF62296F58C0965F066344423E40

In the original table in PG the type of the field is geometry(geometry, 4326)
I would love to understand how to resolve it or maybe get a reference to the correct area in the Airbyte code to understand it myself.
Is there a way to resolve this or should I just handle both cases in the downstream jobs using this field?
Thanks

I understand now that every record that AirByte is capturing in initial capture has a format of binary only and records captured in CDC have the JSON format.
But that still doesn't help me with solving this behavior.
